# laravel 8 project throws 404 error, on server

Tags: amazon-web-services, vuejs3, laravel-8, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

we have deployed our vue3 and laravel 8 project on AWS windows server, it works fine on localhost, but the moment we try to open the homepage of our website on server it throws 404 not found error, other APIs like login and singup etc have been working fine though, this problem lies with only the homepage

On devtools network it shows cancelled status for few of the assets files and images, but on hard refresh the cancelled status shifts to other assets other files.